# CAML query on external list not looking beyond ECT filter limit

Tags: 2010, spservices, external-content-type, caml

I have an external list which is tied to an external content type. The external content type is tied to a SQL table with about 3000 records. I have set up a Read Item operation, and a Read List operation with the required limit filter, set to 2000. Tried > 2000, it doesn't allow it. I have a CAML query, being done in a NewForm.aspx page via SPServices using the GetListItems() method.

The external list has four columns; ID (int32), username (string), foo1 (string), foo2 (string). The ID column is the primary key.

My CAML query is attempting to pick typically one or two records out of the external list, querying for rows containing a particular username. I can get the query to work, but it only returns results if they are within the 2000 records included in the Read List limit filter. I have spent hours googling, and trying every imaginable attempt at using the wildcard filter paramater, the comparison filter parameter, and all the options I could throw at the CAML query itself.

This is so maddening, so typically SharePointy. Is there any way of getting the query to search the entire external content list, regardless of the limit filter, since it is only going to be returning a handful of records?  This is for SP2010

Answer (score 0):

http://akanoongo.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-resolve-2000-items-resolution-in.html has a PowerShell script which, when ran as farm admin, will increase the External Content Type row filter limt from 2,000 to 20,000. I tried it on our test/dev system, and it works.